# Kafka Streams produce messages conditionally after transformation

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

We have a use-case, where we have to read some messages into the KStreams, then transform the message and produce it to another topic conditionally.

In our use-case, for transformation of object, we make an downstream API call. If the API call is succesfull, then produce to newTopic1, else produce to newTopic2. How can the same be achieved ??

As of now, we are using the below style of producing the enriched (i.e. transformed objects) to the new Kafka topic using ***to*** method provided by Streams API.

```
KStream<String, Customer> transformedStream = sourceKafkaStream
                .mapValues(cust -> {
                    try {
                        logger.info("Hitting to the downstream to fetch additional information, will take few seconds.");
                        Thread.sleep(7000);
                        return RecordEnrichmentAndTransformationBuilder.enrichTheCustomer(cust);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return cust;
                });
                .to('newTopic1', Produced.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.serdeForEnrichedCustomer()));
```

Appreciate the response on this.

Answer (score 1):

Using DSL api you use `KStream::filter` or `KStream:to(TopicNameExtractor<K, V> topicExtractor, Produced<K, V> produced)`.

Sample code will looks like that if both format are the same:

```
KStream<String, Customer> transformedStream = sourceKafkaStream
                .mapValues(cust -> {
                    try {
                        logger.info("Hitting to the downstream to fetch additional information, will take few seconds.");
                        Thread.sleep(7000);
                        return RecordEnrichmentAndTransformationBuilder.enrichTheCustomer(cust);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return cust;
                });
                .to((key, value, recordContext) -> topicNameCalculation(key, value), Produced.with(AppSerdes.String(), AppSerdes.serdeForEnrichedCustomer()));
```

`topicNameCalculation(...)` will based on the key and the value chose the proper topic.

**One Notice**
Generally it is not good approach to make external call in Kafka Streams.

Comment: Thanks @Bartosz for your answer. Can you please elaborate why it is not a good idea to make external calls in Kafka streams. I would appreciate the design philisophy you might have. We are extensively planning to levy the streams with external API calls.

Comment: @AdityaGoel, There are several reasons, for instance:
 - If the call will last "too" long rebalance can occure
 - If the call is not idempotent, business logic can be broken. Kafka Streams can invoke call several times for same the same message (Exactly once is only within Kafka).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is there no way to control the timeout / heartbeat time for a stream-task ?

Comment: @AdityaGoel, you can control all that.

Comment: Is this property max.poll.interval.ms not defaults to Integer.MAX_VALUE ? @Bartosz